# how to add dynamically the select box in custom form in foundation framework

Tags: zurb-foundation

i have a problem in adding select box dynamically in custom forms in foundation css framework.even if i add select within the form that have class name "custom".its added normal style select box only.

```
<pre>
var createdRow ="<tr><td><select><option value='1'>1</option></select></td></tr>";                       
jQuery('#roomsDetails tbody').append(createdRow);
</pre>
```

Answer (score 5):

run this code after u added select

```
Foundation.libs.forms.assemble();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add style to the element, just use `jQuery('option').addClass('some css class');` or `jQuery('option').css('property', 'value');`

Comment: This question is specifically related to dynamic added select element not styled properly (because some javascript need to be called), not about general jQuery manipulation.